# how to have a onesignal notification turn off?

Tags: android, android-studio

I use OneSignal push notifications. Everything works well but I want to notifications turn off with toggle buttons.
How to ı use.

Here is code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Yükleniyor...");
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressDialog.show();

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.Wview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");


    //OneSignal.setLogLevel(OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.DEBUG, OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.DEBUG);
    // Onesignal başlıyor

   OneSignal.startInit(this)
            .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
            .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
            .init();}
```